# MySQL Workbench doesn't show columns when I alter the table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the table "giorno",I want to alter it but no columns are showed and I can't even add a new column because the existing columns are not shown either, se the screenshot below:

[image]

I also tried to create a new table but it appears the same bug. So I can't add new columns.

How is it possible? Maybe I made a mistake with my settings?

Comment: what happens if you run a `show create table giorno` command from mysqlworkbench?

Comment: @Shadow it shows all columns correctly

Comment: This means that there is nothing wrong with the underlying database. Have you checked if your user can query the information_schema database? `select * from information_schema.columns where table_name='giorno'`

Comment: @Shadow yes it works

Comment: In this case the issue is with MySQL workbench, which is not really  sw development related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have 3 tables and any of them has a primary key. I just changed one key from Primary to Index and now everything is working.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case anyone else runs into this. Just click the arrow on the top right (next to schema).

[image: this arrow]

Comment: This is what worked for me as well, somehow mine were hidden and clicking the arrow(s) did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

On the right of your screen i can see two scrollbar arrows. Please try to place your mouse pointer there and resize the window.(Its in the same line with the Column Name,Datatype,PK...)

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a bug. I had the same issue, but it was stopping after a 
`timestamp(6) / on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)` 
field. I had to change it to a straight `date(6)` field with no `on update` clause, and the rest of the fields then appeared.

After that, I went back and changed my field back to `timestamp(6) / on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)` and the table editor displayed everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For me restarting the workbench solved the problem!